# Which Mission is implied by the purport of Gita 10.42?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, iskcon

[image][image]The 'Bhagavad-Gita As It Is', 'the best-selling and most authorative version of this classic of world literature', by Bhaktivedanta Swami, 'the world's foremost Vedic scholar and teacher', reads in the purport of the sloka 10.42 (2nd edition, page 480):

> '**There is a Mission that regularly propounds that worship of any demigod will lead one to the Supreme Personality of Godhead, or the supreme goal.But worship of demigods is thoroughly discouraged herein**..'

My question is :Different Missions exist having different translations and explanations of the Gita. Which particular body is being referred to here as 'A Mission', that is being mentioned as spreading a message which is thoroughly discouraged by the Gita?

[image]

Comment: I think you can cut down on the sarcasm.

Comment: @LazyLubber each and every word i wrote are quotations except the question.So where did you find sarcasm? Please let me know.

Comment: @LazyLubber There is no doubt in the fact that it is the most popular and accepted version of the Gita.

Comment: 'the best-selling and most authorative version of this classic of world literature', 'the world's foremost Vedic scholar and teacher', Unduoubtedly this explanation throws a new light to the purport of this particular sloka of Gita, **which NO Acharya could decipher**. All these look sarcastic.

Comment: @Parimaputra just leave the sarcasm out the next time.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu All these are quotations from a most well known book and there is no scope of sarcasm here

Comment: That does not mean you should put it here it has no added value to your question.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu i think it does because at least some of the so much read version, which is NOT exaggeration, must be aware of the Mission that my question refer to I hope.

Comment: Just add which version of the Gita that should suffice.

Comment: It's not quite clear which mission he is referring to, but it could be there are several missions which teach that thing.